# controlling other screen html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Basically I have two screens (on different monitors), one works as a controller of the other which  simply displays to the audience. I am planning to use HTML for displaying the contents in both the screens.
Currently I am stuck up on how to control the second screen using the actions on the first in realtime, say if I click a button on the first, an image should popup on the second. Can someone help me out on how to control the second page using the first? TIA

Comment: questions not clear. how can u view two different screen in a single tab?

Comment: Are the two monitors connected to the same (i.e. [dual monitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-monitor)) or different computer? Can you please clarify?

Comment: They are connected to the same computer. And the two screens will have separate browser windows.

Comment: Hi @Sagar. Please note that [comments are temporary and could be deleted anytime](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). If you have additional information to provide, please update your question by clicking on the **"[edit]"** link under the post. [See here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/204869) for details. Thank you.

Comment: Are the two browser windows running on the same browser? I mean, are they both running, say, Chrome? Or is one running Firefox and the other running Safari? If they are running in the same browser but different windows / tabs, there could be a solution with inter-tab communication; if not, you would need a solution with inter-process communication.

Answer (score 0):

if you're talking about two pages, then you need a backend to do so.
you will have to retrieve the action committed on screen 1 (page 1) into your back code, and then transmit the information you want to all connections on the second screen (page 2).
Alternatively you could also submit the action into a database and have screen 2 read this information and behave accordingly every 2 seconds or so.
I wouldn't recommend going with option 2 since it costs too much resources which will lead your program to slow down and potentially behave abnormally.
If this is not the answer you're looking for please edit your question to clarify  your objectives.